# is there a rails method to loop through each line of uploaded file? "each_line" is an IO method but it's not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, loops, parameters

I'm attempting to upload a csv file, parse it, and spit out a file for S3 or just pass to view.  I use a file_field_tag to upload the csv.  I thought file_field_tag passes an object that is a subclass of IO and would have all ruby IO methods such as "each_line".  I can call "read" on the object (method of IO class) but not "each_line"... so how can I iterate over each line of a file_field_tag upload?

create method of my controller as:

```
@csv_file = params[:csv_file]
```

My show view which throws a no "each_line" method error:

```
<% @csv_file.each_line do |line| %>
<%= line %>
<% end %>
```

Yet I can use

```
<%= @csv_file.read(100) %>
```

I'm really confused what methods a file_field_tag upload params[] has... each_line, gets don't work... I can't seem to find a list of what I can use.

**EDIT**
I worked around this by doing:

```
@csv_file = params[:csv_file].read.to_s
```

then iterated through with:

```
<% @sp_file.each_line do |line| %>
<%= line %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 2**
The file being uploaded has repeats the header after lines which don't contain a comma (don't ask)... So I find lines without a comma and call .gets (in my rb script independent of rails).  Unfortunately I get an error about gets being a private method I can't call.  Which goes back to my initial issue being.  Aren't files a sub class of IO with IO methods like read_lines & gets?

```
        @file_out = []
        @file_in.each_line do |line|
            case line
            when /^[^,]+$/
                @comp = line.to_s.strip
                comp_header = @file_in.gets.strip.split('')

                @file_out.push(@comp)
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post a 'file_field' ,  the param returned to the controller has some special magic hooked in.

I.e.  in your case you could this

```
<%= "The following file was uploaded #{params[:csv_file].original_filename}" %>
<%= "It's content type was #{params[:csv_file].content_type}" %>
<%= "The content of the file is as follows: #{params[:csv_file].read}" %>
```

So those are the three special methods you can call on params[:csv_file], or any params posted as the result of a successful 'file_field_tag' or 'f.file_field' in a view

Just remember that those are the three extra special things you can to to a param posted as a result of a file_field:

original_filename

content_type

read

You've clearly figured out how to do the read,  the original_filename and content_type may help you out in the future.

EDIT

OK,  so all you have is the read method,  which will read the contents of the file uploaded.

```
contents = params[:csv_file].read
```

So now contents is a string containing the contents of the file,  but nothing else is known about that file EXCEPT that it's a csv file.  We know that csvs are delimited with '\r' (I think, I've done a lot of work with parsing csv's,  but I'm too lazy to go check)

so you could do this:

```
contents = params[:csv_file].read
contents.split("\r").each do |csvline|
  ???
end
```

EDIT 2

so here is the take away from this post

When you post a file_field to a controller,  the most common thing to do with the contents of the uploaded file is 'read' it into a ruby String.  Any additional processing of the uploaded contents must be done on that ruby String returned from the 'read'.

In this particular case,  if the uploaded file is ALWAYS a CSV,  you can just assume the CSV and start parsing it accordingly.  If you expect multiple upload formats,  you have to deal with that,  for example:

```
contents = params[:csv_file].read
case params[:csv_file].content_type
when 'txt/csv'
  contents.split("\r").each do |csvline| 
    ???
  end
when 'application/pdf'
  ???
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't understand how my file hasn't inherited IO methods... I can't figure out how to get a .gets to work!

Comment: I just edited my question with some more code I thought would work!  Thanks!  Per you answer I did a content_type and it confined txt/csv... SO I guess the object is txt/csv and only has access to thos methods?... BUT gets is alias for shift in CSV!

Comment: So I think I now understand the real gist of your question.  The answer is this: ALL you can do with an uploaded file is 'read' the contents into a string.  Any additional processing of that string has to be done as a Ruby String.  You were expecting that an actual IO stream could be returned from the file_field,  it can't,   you can only read it into a string.

Comment: Thanks to that I used: @file_out = StringIO.new(@csv_file) to convert into IO and use some of those methods!  Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me: @uploaded_file.open.each_line do |line|
  ... 
end